# How to access the realm model list in filter in swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, list, realm

**This is my object/model**

```
import RealmSwift
class IBPChapters: Object {

    @objc dynamic var ibp_chapter_id = 0
    @objc dynamic var chapter = ""
    @objc dynamic var chapter_president = ""
    @objc dynamic var office_no = ""
    @objc dynamic var email_address = ""
    @objc dynamic var services_offered = ""
    var service = List<Services>()
    @objc dynamic var locid = 0
    @objc dynamic var loc:Locations?
    @objc dynamic var status = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "ibp_chapter_id"
    }
}
```

**Services Model**

```
import RealmSwift
class Services: Object{

    @objc dynamic var service_id = 0
    @objc dynamic var service = ""
    @objc dynamic var status = 0
    @objc dynamic var ibp_service_filter = true
    @objc dynamic var pao_service_filter = true
    @objc dynamic var lac_service_filter = true

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "service_id"
    }
}
```

**Example Data**

```
1. legal aid,outreach,counseling,case handling
2. legal aid,counseling
3. outreach,counseling
```

**Appending Data**

*`if chapter.service[0].ibp_service_filter == true` , append all data having legal aid*

**Output** will be `1 and 2` //Expected OUTPUT

*`if chapter.service[1].ibp_service_filter == true`, append all data having counseling but if the id is already exist ignore that index and continue to the next data*

**Output** will be `1 and 2 and 3` //Expected OUTPUT

```
func addData(){

    var ibpArray:[IBPChapters] = []

    let chapters = realm.objects(IBPChapters.self)//condition for filter here
    for chapter in chapters{
        print(chapter.service)
        ibpArray.append(chapter)

        //Legal Aid service[0]
        if chapter.service[0].ibp_service_filter == true{
            ibpArray.append(chapter)
        }
        //Counseling service[1]
        if chapter.service[1].ibp_service_filter == true{
            ibpArray.append(chapter)
        }
        //Outreach service[2]
        if chapter.service[2].ibp_service_filter == true{
            ibpArray.append(chapter)
        }
        //Case Handling service[3]
        if chapter.service[3].ibp_service_filter == true{
            ibpArray.append(chapter)
        }
    }
}
```

**MY OUTPUT** `1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3`//<- wrong output

*only `1 and 2` has legal aid , and all of them `1,2 and 3` has counseling so I dont need to append `1 and 2` again since I already appended them on the array on the first loop*

**How can I access the list on the realm for my filter, so I can manipulate the data or Do you have any idea or alternative way to generate my expected output**

*Can I use array index to filter?* **ex.** `.filter("services[0].ibp.filtered == true)`

**Correct Output**

```
func addData(){

    let chapters = realm.objects(IBPChapters.self)
    for chapter in chapters{
        let filteredServices = chapter.service.filter("ibp_service_filter == true")
        for service in filteredServices{
            let service_index = filteredServices.index(of: service)
            if chapter.service.contains(filteredServices[service_index!]){
                if !ibpArray.contains(where: {$0.ibp_chapter_id == chapter.ibp_chapter_id}){
                    ibpArray.append(chapter)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*but I still want to know if there is a much better answer or shorter than my answer or lets say less loops and conditions*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Realm` support [`.filter()`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) function based on `NSPredicate`. So, first you should get `ibp_service_filter == true` values:

```
let filteredServices = chapter.service.filter("ibp_service_filter == true")
```

and then save only uniq ids (*basic idea*):

```
for service in filteredServices where !history_ibp.contains(where: { $0. service_id == service.service_id }) {
    history_ibp.append(service)
}
```

Comment: i will try that tomorrow , im currently not in the office this time , thank you for your response @pacification

Comment: `Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call` beside the `.contains`

Comment: i deleted the `history_ibp` its not part of the block of code , @pacification  can you edit your answer , i tried your answer and error occured `Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call`

Comment: what is the use of `!` in `!history_ibp` @pacification?

Comment: i will edit my post and add my answer! just try to review if my answer is on the proper way @pacification

Comment: i will mark your answer as correct since you give me a hint which is the `let filteredServices = chapter.service.filter("ibp_service_filter == true")` and `!history_ibp.contains(where: { $0. service_id == service.service_id })` and just make some changes to come up with the right output